# How to append onclick event to li class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to apply this attribute:

```
onclick=​"expandMenu(this.parentNode)​"
```

to every li with the class="parent"

So far I have this and can't get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('li').hasClass('parent'))
{
'onclick' => 'expandMenu(this.parentNode)';
}
</script>
```

This is the browser-side code of the menu, generated by Magento. Each li has an anchor tag inside. I think I need to make those unclickable in order for this to work. What I want to be able to do is expand product categories (like the arrow does) by clicking on the li, rather than have it take you to the page:

```
<div id="sidebar-nav" class="sidebar-nav-left">
<div class="block-title">
<strong><span>Categories</span></strong> 
</div>
<div class="block-content">
<ul id="sidebar-nav-menu">
<li class="level0 nav-1 first parent" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 10px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="tion.html"><span class="category_name">tion</span></a>
</div>
<ul class="level0" style="margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 10px;" expanded="0">
<li class="level1 nav-1-1 first parent" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 10px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="system.html"><span class="category_name">System</span></a>
</div>
<ul class="level1" style="margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 10px;" expanded="0">
<li class="level2 nav-1-1-1 first last" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
a href="accessories.html"><span class="category_name">Accessories</span></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li><li class="level1 nav-1-2" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="pack.html"><span class="category_name">Pack</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level1 nav-1-3" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="system.html"><span class="category_name">System</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level1 nav-1-4 parent" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 10px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="accessories.html"><span class="category_name"> Accessories</span></a>
</div>
<ul class="level1" style="margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 10px;" expanded="0">
<li class="level2 nav-1-4-2 first" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="needles.html"><span class="category_name"> Needles</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level2 nav-1-4-3" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="cha.html"><span class="category_name">Percha</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level2 nav-1-4-4" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="condensers.html"><span class="category_name">Condensers</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level2 nav-1-4-5" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="resilon.html"><span class="category_name">Resinate</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level2 nav-1-4-6 last" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="pluggers.html"><span class="category_name">Heat</span></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li><li class="level1 nav-1-5" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="heat.html"><span class="category_name">Heat</span></a>
</div>
</li><li class="level1 nav-1-6 last" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<span class="arrow" onClick="expandMenu(this.parentNode)" 
style="width: 8px; height: 0px;"></span>

<div class="collapsible-wrapper" style="margin-left: 14px;">
<a href="replacement-parts.html"><span class="category_name">Parts</span></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>        </ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so are you wanting only the anchor tags that don't have a parent `li` with the class `parent` to work as an actual link and take you to another page.  If it does have a parent `li` with a class `parent` then it will expand?  Hope that made sense

Comment: I want any `li` with the class `parent` that doesn't have a parent `li` to expand. Any that do have a parent `li` should take you to another page.

Comment: check out my new answer below and see if thats what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the below

```
$("li.parent").click(function()
{
    expandMenu(this.parentNode);
});
```

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/87vN2/)

Below is an updated version on what I think you are looking for.

It will detect an link click and check its parent `li` for the class `parent`.  If it finds the class it will prevent the link and expand the menu.  If it doesn't find the class the link works as it should

```
$("#sidebar-nav-menu a").click(function()
{
    if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("parent"))
    {       
        expandMenu(($(this).parent()).parentNode);
        //return flase prevents the anchor link from working
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

you didn't tell us you redefined the jquery `$` to `jQuery`

put this in your `unclick.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() 
{ 
    jQuery("#sidebar-nav-menu li.level0 > div > a").click(function() 
    {
        if(jQuery(this).parent().parent().hasClass("parent")) 
        { 
            expandMenu(this.parentNode.parentNode); 
            //return flase prevents the anchor link from working 
            return false;
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Still not working, but the li menu is dynamically generated in Magento with anchor links in each li. Is there a way to make those anchors unclickable with js? I posted the browser-side code above.

Comment: @miles Technically it does work but you have nested `li` which causes the click to fire on a nested `li` that has a parent `li` with a class of `parent` even though it doesn't have the class `parent`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But for some reason it's only working on the first `parent` `li`, even when subsequent items are clicked. Check the link to see what I mean.

Comment: It's also expanding the 2nd level `li` that have a parent. Any way we can prevent that and just go to the link instead?

Comment: @miles so you are wanting only the very first parent to do the expand?

Answer (score 3):

This will work for all of the `li` elements with the `parent` class *currently* on the document:

```
$('li.parent').on('click', function(){
    expandMenu(this.parentNode);
});
```

However, if you want to do this for *future* elements that may be added later, you can use this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'li.parent', function(){
    expandMenu(this.parentNode);
});
```

*Edit*

As far as preventing the links from firing, you can use this code:

```
$('#sidebar-nav-menu a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

But that will prevent *all* of the links on the menu from firing (except links added *after* the call to this method);

*Edit Again*

Finally, we can use this, which will only fire off the links that do *not* have sub-menus.

```
$('#sidebar-nav-menu a').on('click', function(e) {

    if($(this).parent().siblings('ul').length)
    {
        // If my anchor is associated with a sub-catagory, prevent it from firing.
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    expandMenu(this.parentNode);
});
```

Comment: your sidebar edit doesn't work correctly.  you need to have `#` in front of it

Comment: +1, yes keep that event management out of the markup and IN the code where it belongs :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want use jQuery, all you must do is adding below code to this file:
[your_magento_root]/skin/frontend/default/default/js/sidenavcollapse.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() 
{
    $('#sidebar-nav-menu div.collapsible-wrapper').click(function(){
        expandMenu(this.parentNode);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Don't forget loading jQuery library. If you like do this in other way like editing generated HTMLs, please let me know, I'll say about it.

**Edit:**

We return false to deactivating "a" tag's "href".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the attribute. Use the jQuery [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function:

```
$('li.parent').click(function(){
    expandMenu(this.parentNode);
});
```