# Make <div>, <li> clickable without <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a `<div>` or `<li>` tag to be clickable (the pointer should change to hand). How can I do it without `<a>` tag?

Because, when a  div is clicked, my javascript loads a text file.

Comment: `onclick` comes to mind...

Comment: can you be more specific? you mean `<div onclick>` ?

Comment: show your `javascript` maybe it can help to answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append onclick event to li class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402459/how-to-append-onclick-event-to-li-class)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add `style="cursor:pointer"` for the hand pointer and `onclick="window.location='somewhere'"`.

```
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location='index.html'">My Link</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myel = document.querySelector('#myel'); // your element

myel.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

In CSS:

```
#myel { cursor: pointer }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it a number of ways. one way is to assign the pseudo class in your css. if the div has a class of div1 then our css would read:

```
.div1:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

You can also do it in javascript

```
$('.div1').on("hover", function(){
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Set the css:

```
ul li{
  cursor:pointer; /*  <------this will change the cursor to hand cursor*/
}
```

### and jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('li').click(function(){
      alert('li clicked.');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...

**CSS**

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer //on hover change the cursor to pointer
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#click_me").bind("click", function(){ //bind a click event on an element with id = click_me
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "./file.txt", //note: file must be in the same domain as the current script http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) { //if ajax request is successful
                $("#result_container").html(data); //append the resulting data into a div with id = result_container
        }
    });
});
```

});

Cheers :)